# GCM for iOS, gcm connection handler is never called

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-messaging

I'm implementing Google Cloud Messaging in my application. I've followed the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client?ver=swift) given in google documentations. I can send notifications to my device with HTTP POST request, but the problem is that in the applicationDidBecomeActive, as google showed, I try to connect with gcmService but **the connectionHandler block is never called**.

*applicationDidBecomeActive function in my AppDelegate*

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {


    GCMService.sharedInstance().connectWithHandler({
        (NSError error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print("Could not connect to GCM: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            self.connectedToGCM = true
            print("Connected to GCM")

            self.subscribeToTopic()
        }
    })
}
```

Does any one have solved this issue?

**EDIT - This is the correct way**

Here is my complete AppDelegate.swift file

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//

import UIKit
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GGLInstanceIDDelegate, GCMReceiverDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    var connectedToGCM = false
    var gcmSenderID: String?
    var gcmRegistrationToken: String?
    var gcmRegistrationOptions = [String: AnyObject]()
    let gcmRegistrationKey = "onRegistrationCompleted"
    var subscribedToTopic = false

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        print("bundleId=\(NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier)")

        // Configure Google Analytics
        // Configure tracker from GoogleService-Info.plist.
        var configureError:NSError?
        GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
        assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")

        // Optional: configure GAI options.
        let gai = GAI.sharedInstance()
        gai.trackUncaughtExceptions = true  // report uncaught exceptions
        gai.logger.logLevel = GAILogLevel.Verbose  // remove before app release


        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil))  // types are UIUserNotificationType members
        // Register for remotes notifications
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()

        // Get the gcm sender id
        gcmSenderID = GGLContext.sharedInstance().configuration.gcmSenderID

        var gcmConfig = GCMConfig.defaultConfig()
        gcmConfig.receiverDelegate = self
        GCMService.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(gcmConfig)

        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
        GCMService.sharedInstance().disconnect()

        connectedToGCM = false
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.

        // -->The app go through this point
        // Connect to the GCM server to receive non-APNS notifications
        GCMService.sharedInstance().connectWithHandler(gcmConnectionHandler)
        // -->The app go through this point
    }

    func gcmConnectionHandler(error: NSError?) {
        // -->The app never enter in this function
        if let error = error {
            print("Could not connect to GCM: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            self.connectedToGCM = true
            print("Connected to GCM")
            // ...
        }
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
        self.saveContext()
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {

        // Create a config and set a delegate that implements the GGLInstaceIDDelegate protocol.
        let instanceIDConfig = GGLInstanceIDConfig.defaultConfig()
        instanceIDConfig.delegate = self
        // Start the GGLInstanceID shared instance with that config and request a registration
        // token to enable reception of notifications
        GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(instanceIDConfig)
        gcmRegistrationOptions = [kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken,
            kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:true]
        GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().tokenWithAuthorizedEntity(gcmSenderID,
            scope: kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM, options: gcmRegistrationOptions, handler: gcmRegistrationHandler)

    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
        print("-- Failed to get deviceToken: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber += 1

        print(userInfo)
        let apsInfo = userInfo["aps"] as! NSDictionary

        var alertMessage = ""
        print("********************** Received Notif")

        if let alert = apsInfo["alert"] as? String{
            alertMessage = alert
            print(alertMessage)
        }
        else if let alert = apsInfo["alert"] as? NSDictionary, let body = alert["body"] as?  String {
            alertMessage = body
            print(alertMessage)
        }


        // If the application is currently on screen "Active" then we trigger a custom banner View for that notification to be shown
        // Else the system will handle that and put it in the notification center
        if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Active {
            AGPushNoteView.showWithNotificationMessage(alertMessage, autoClose: true, completion: { () -> Void in
                // Do nothing
            })
        }
    }


    func gcmRegistrationHandler(registrationToken: String!, error: NSError!) {
        if (registrationToken != nil) {
            self.gcmRegistrationToken = registrationToken
            print("GCM Registration Token: \(registrationToken)")
            let userInfo = ["registrationToken": registrationToken]
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
                self.gcmRegistrationKey, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
        } else {
          print("Registration to GCM failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            let userInfo = ["error": error.localizedDescription]
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(self.gcmRegistrationKey, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - GGLInstanceIDDelegate
    func onTokenRefresh() {
        // A rotation of the registration tokens is happening, so the app needs to request a new token.
        print("The GCM registration token needs to be changed.")
        GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().tokenWithAuthorizedEntity(gcmSenderID,
            scope: kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM, options: gcmRegistrationOptions, handler: gcmRegistrationHandler)
    }


    // MARK: - GCMReceiverDelegate
    func willSendDataMessageWithID(messageID: String!, error: NSError!) {
        if (error != nil) {
            // Failed to send the message.
        } else {
            // Will send message, you can save the messageID to track the message
        }
    }

    func didSendDataMessageWithID(messageID: String!) {
        // Did successfully send message identified by messageID
    }
    // [END upstream_callbacks]

    func didDeleteMessagesOnServer() {
        // Some messages sent to this device were deleted on the GCM server before reception, likely
        // because the TTL expired. The client should notify the app server of this, so that the app
        // server can resend those messages.
    }

    func subscribeToTopic() {
        // If the app has a registration token and is connected to GCM, proceed to subscribe to the
        // topic
        let subscriptionTopic = "/topics/test-global"
        if(gcmRegistrationToken != nil && connectedToGCM) {
            GCMPubSub.sharedInstance().subscribeWithToken(gcmRegistrationToken, topic: subscriptionTopic,
                options: nil, handler: {(NSError error) -> Void in
                    if (error != nil) {
                        // Treat the "already subscribed" error more gently
                        if error.code == 3001 {
                            print("Already subscribed to \(subscriptionTopic)")
                        } else {
                            print("Subscription failed: \(error.localizedDescription)");
                        }
                    } else {
                        subscribedToTopic = true;
                        NSLog("Subscribed to \(subscriptionTopic)");
                    }
            })
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple problems in your code.

First, you need to call `GCMService.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(GCMConfig.defaultConfig())` in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, but you only called it in `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` method.

Second, you should call `application.registerForRemoteNotifications()` after `application.registerUserNotificationSettings()` in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

There is a [sample GCM project for iOS](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/ios/gcm) available, you can follow the [sample implementation](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/ios/gcm/GcmExampleSwift/AppDelegate.swift) for `AppDelegate.swift` file, so that your app will work correctly.

You can also get the GCM iOS sample project via Cocoapods by doing `pod try Google`, you can visit [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/start) for more details.

Edited:

You should replace the lines in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` with the following (notice that you should use `let gcmConfig = GCMConfig.defaultConfig()` and `gcmConfig.receiverDelegate = self`):

```
    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    // Configure the Google context: parses the GoogleService-Info.plist, and initializes
    // the services that have entries in the file
    var configureError:NSError?
    GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
    assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")
    gcmSenderID = GGLContext.sharedInstance().configuration.gcmSenderID
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
    // Register for remote notifications
    let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
        UIUserNotificationSettings( forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil )
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings( settings )
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    // [END register_for_remote_notifications]
    // [START start_gcm_service]
    var gcmConfig = GCMConfig.defaultConfig()
    gcmConfig.receiverDelegate = self
    GCMService.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(gcmConfig)
    // [END start_gcm_service]
    return true
```

Comment: I put the `startWithConfig` in my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method but my handler for `connectWithHandler` is still never called.
Regarding the `registerForRemoteNotification` call it is made later in my app after the user logged in. Notifications send by my server to the registration token are working correctly. 

But the issue is that I can't connect to gcm services to send reception status, or send messages from the device.

As I'm using Swift 2 on Xcode 7, is it possible that this is related to new error management using try/catch blocks instead of NSError pointers ?

Comment: I updated the code. I also marked with '-->' the point were there is the issue

Comment: Again, you still dont have `application.registerForRemoteNotifications()` in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: like I said in reply to your comment the registerForRemoteNotifications is called elsewhere in my code because I need that. The registration works as I receive the device Token from apple and then I request the gcm registration id and get it correctly. The thing that doesn't work is the connection to gcm service on the phone.

Comment: I also tried (and edited the code in the AppDelegate), with the `registerForRemoteNotifications` in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method it doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: As I said in the edited answer, did you use `let gcmConfig = GCMConfig.defaultConfig()`, `gcmConfig.receiverDelegate = self` and `GCMService.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(gcmConfig)`

Comment: Sorry I didn't noticed that I needed to use both `GCMService.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(gcmConfig)` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` AND `GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(instanceIDConfig)` in the `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` 

Thank you for your help and I marked this answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that you have defined NSAppTransportSecurity key is in your plist.[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This property was not set but now it is and it still don't fix my issue. Any other ideas?

Comment: I dont think you need to set the `NSAppTransportSecurity` key to `YES` in order to let your `connectWithHandler` closure get called. It is possible that your `GCMService.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(GCMConfig.defaultConfig())` was not used in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method. please paste the full code of your appDelegate file. Also you can give a line break in the line `print("Connected to GCM")`

Comment: @ztan I updated my post with the `AppDelegate`. As described in the start guide by google, the `startWithConfig` method is called just before requesting the device token in the `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`